# How to add assign group to the user when created user in Azure Ad

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, active-directory-group

I am creating user [as described on Create user - Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_users)

And I know how to add member into group [as described on Add member - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_members)

But I don't want to perform two operations, I want to assign membership while creating the user. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method we can assign the user to a group when creating the user. We need to assign the group after creating the user successfully(HTTP 200 response).

If you want this feature in Microsoft Graph, you can submit the feedback from [this link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/20320891-need-group-assignment-support-while-creating-user